# Make Windows Integrated Form Style In Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, themes, skinning

Every Delphi 7 developer knows that if he compile a application on Delphi 7, the style will be as Windows 2000 applications, but there is any method to make this better as the application can have the default theme of the Windows version, as C++ and C# applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding the TXPManifest component to the main form of your application. located in the Win32 Tab.

[image]

The TXPManifest component has no methods or properties. All it does is include the XPMan unit in your project. This in turn causes a certain resource file to be included in your project's executable file. The resource includes a manifest - a small piece of XML that contains information about the application you are writing as well as information concerning the version of the comctl32.dll to use.

Comment: ... or just "manually" add XPMan to the uses clause of your project's *.dpr file.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively add your own manifest resource manually - which allows you to tap into the even newer Windows 7 features, if you can be bothered to fathom out the syntax. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748757/delphi-windows-aero-resources/1749331#1749331) for more info but ignore the bit about enabling runtime themes as this doesn't exist in D7 (I don't think).