# VirtualStore for delphi application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use opendialog to load file to application path . is there any way to load the file to **%userprofile% > AppData > Local > VirtualStore > Program Files > MyApplication Folder**, it is because users should not see the the loaded file

Comment: or any other trick to hide opendialog file from end user  in app path

Answer (score 1):

Windows will automatically show applications the "VirtualStore" files for old applications.  This is done to try and make sure that old applications build before UAC continue to run correctly.  To turn off this behavior you need to add a application manifest to your program.  This will make windows turn off the VirtualStore behavior both for files and registry entries.

Here is a good page that describes what is happening in detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware

> The manifest is an XML resource file that can be embedded into the application. In terms of UAC, this serves 2 purposes. Firstly it tells the operating system that the application has been designed with UAC in mind, and that it therefore should not attempt to virtualize any folders or registry settings. If the application still attempts to access protected resources after making its declaration, then these requests will simply fail rather than virtualize. The other thing it does is allow the application to state the privilege level at which it needs to run, and whether it requires elevation.

There are several questions already on StackOverflow that deal with creating and adding an application manifest to Delphi 7 projects.  Here is one link to get you started:
[Delphi 7 vista / windows 7 manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757533/delphi-7-vista-windows-7-manifest)

Once you tell windows that you know about the new version of Windows via the manifest you will need to make sure that you are playing by the new rules and don't write data back to any of the protected locations.